# String can't be parsed into Date "Swift"

Tags: ios, swift, date, parsing, nsdate

I'm trying to parse the following String input "**2020-04-05 19:02:02**" into Date, which I'm using the following code to do that:

```
static func getDateFromString(_ dateStr: String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"
    dateFormater.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    return dateFormater.date(from: dateStr)
}
```

The problem is that not working, it returns nil

Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you show a [mcve]? Are you sure the input string is what it is?

Comment: it's working no problem  just check your input string

Comment: You need to set your date formatter’s locale to “en_US_POSIX” before setting your date format

Comment: Note that H is for 1-23 hours for leading  zero hours 00-23 you need to use HH

Comment: Thank you all, it's Xcode problem

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this works fine:

In dateString pass data in string format and for dateFormat pass format you want and to choose format use [NSDateFormatter](https://nsdateformatter.com):

```
let expiryDateString = "2020-04-05 19:02:02"
let dateformat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let expireDate = DateHelper.getDateFrom(expireDateString, dateformat)
static func getDateFrom(dateString: String,dateFormat: String) -> Date? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
        dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
        guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else {return nil}
        return date
}
```

Comment: It seems the function has value already, but when I try to return it into variable it becomes nil, for example: `let expireDate = DateHelper.getDateFromString(expireDateString)`

Comment: the **expireDate** variable is nil

Comment: That's too weird, that's never happened in my entire programing life

Comment: It's ok It seems a compiling problem from Xcode, I just cleaned the project then I rebuild

Comment: Thank you anyway, I really appreciate it

Comment: Sounds great! (Y) @AbdHayek